# In Season 2 do I play as Clementine, or someone else?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-two

I recently finished playing The Walking Dead Season 1 (and the 400 Days DLC), and I'm probably going to buy Season 2 very soon. However the one thing I'm not sure about is who I'll be playing as. I'm also trying to avoid spoiling myself as much as possible.

Will I be playing as Clementine, or do you rotate through playable characters like in the 400 Days DLC? In the main game (Season 1) I'm pretty sure that it never let me play anyone aside besides Lee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes, the season features Clementine as the main playable protagonist.](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Season_2_(Video_Game)#.22All_That_Remains.22)

Edit: Click at your own risk, contains spoilers.

Comment: Note: you'll probably don't want to click the link because of spoilers, but +1 anyway :)

Comment: Yeah, although I'd argue that the question itself is a spoiler

Comment: For @KernelPanic himself it isn't, because he did want to know (not sure why though). But if he want to spoil himself as little as possible, no questions at all should be asked. It would be a major spoiler if the answer was no

Comment: @Mathias711 I asked, because to me it was kind of a deal breaker. Mainly, because I LOVED Lee/Clementine thus so far. Anyway SE is probably not the best place for me to avoid spoilers... Thanks for the help.